# Screen won't fit to widescreen tv Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, screen

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with my monitor as a vizio widescreen tv. I'm having difficulty fitting the screen properly. My graphics card is an Nvidia Geforce GT 610. The recommended aspect ratio is 1920x1080. However when I set this aspect ratio, the edges of my desktop are running off the screen. I found that by using  Nvidia conrol panel, I can underscan and and it fits to the screen better but the problem now is that the items on the upper right hand desktop toolbar (clock, network settings) are now cut off. How do I get this set properly?

Comment: You may need to change TV's settings, also.

Comment: Definitely you need to change the TV's settings... By default TVs do overscan (to compensate for cable boxes). It's either in one of the settings menus or just a key in your remote.